# nested iterations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with about 25 sheets and each sheet contains 5-30 columns with system names as headers. I want to iterate through a list of about 170 systems (the list is on one of the sheets in the main file) and with each system search each tab for columns with the matching system as the header. I have the code below and it works great for the first iteration, but for some reason after it loops through all the sheets and moves on to the second system it pulls the sheet name rather than the second system name. Anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = pd.ExcelFile('file')
names_tab = pd.read_excel(matrix, sheet_name='Name_Test')

sheets_list = {}

for (y, sysRows) in names_tab.iterrows():
    print(sysRows['header'])

    for sheets in matrix.sheet_names[1:]:
        sheets_list['{}'.format(sheets)] = pd.read_excel(matrix, sheet_name='{}'.format(sheets), skiprows=2)
        print(sheets)

        for column in sheets_list[sheets]:

            if column == sysRows['header']:
                for idx, row in sheets_list[sheets][column].iteritems():
                    if sheets_list[sheets].iloc[idx][column] == 'x':
                        print('{} has X in row {} column {} on sheet {}'
                              .format(sysRows['header'], idx, column, sheets))
                    elif sheets_list[sheets].iloc[idx][column] == 'X':
                        print('{} has X in row {} column {} on sheet {}'
                              .format(sysRows['header'], idx, column, sheets))
                print(column + ' works')
            else:
                print(column + ' doesnt work')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure this is the same result you are trying to achieve, but hopefully it is a starting point (I doubt you need 4 for loops):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

names_tab = pd.DataFrame({'header':['System1','System2','System3'], 'some_other_column':['foo','bar','foobar']})
sheet1 = pd.DataFrame({'System1':['x','X'], 'System2':['x','X'], 'System4':['X','x']})
sheet2 = pd.DataFrame({'System2':['X','x'], 'System8':['x','x'], 'System3':['x','X']})
sheets = [sheet1, sheet2]
for i, sheet in enumerate(sheets):
    print("Sheet", i + 1)
    common_columns = list(set(sheet.columns.tolist()).intersection(names_tab['header'].tolist()))
    df = sheet[common_columns]
    print("Here are all the 'x' values in Sheet", i + 1)
    print(df.where(df == 'x'))
    # To get your behavior
    positions = np.where(df.values == 'x')
    for idx, col in positions:
        print('{} has x in row {} column {} on sheet {}'.format(df.columns[col], idx, col, str(i+1)))
```

Perhaps you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah i figured 4 for loops wasn't the most efficient way to do it, but it's a relatively small data set so it should still run quickly. I ended up updating the top part to the following and it's working now.

`while sysCount < 164:
    sys_list.append(names_tab.iloc[sysCount, 0])
    sysCount = sysCount + 1`